# X-Azure-ExternalError 0x830c1011: 'The certificate authority is unfamiliar' for Azure Front Door Standard with custom domain with https

Tags: azure-front-door

We have a new Azure Front Door Standard profile resource that has been configured to use acustom domain.  Origin and routes look correct.  When we issue a request to the origin directly, it is working as expected.  However, when we issue requests through the Front Door profile, we get the following error in headers(sent with the X-Azure-DebugInfo header):

X-Azure-ExternalError: 0x830c1011, 'The certificate authority is unfamiliar.'

The actual error in the browser is: 'Request cannot be served.'

The certificate we have on the website is a Go Daddy wildcard certificate chain (multiple cert crt files combined).  We've tried running curl with options and openssl to see if we can see where there is a problem with one of the certificates (against the origin site), but both of them indicate that the certificates are correct.

I have had a look at this page as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-route-matching?pivots=front-door-standard-premium, but it hasn't helped.

I have also checked this page: https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/microsoft/IncludedCACertificateReportForMSFT

to ensure that the Go Daddy root cert in my chain is on this page.  I can confirm that it is (2796BAE63F1801E277261BA0D77770028F20EEE4).

I have turned on diagnostics. Is there any way i can see the actual request being made from front door to our origin to see if there is something weird in the request?  What else could be the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This app was running on an aks, which responds with a fake certificate if a request was made to the root host name or ip address, and not directly using the configured custom hostname. It turns out that when frontdoor makes a request, there a request setup that involves querying the ip/root hostname before frontdoor makes the request to the custom hostname request.

The fix for this involves making sure either the aks doesn't respond to root hostname requests on tls with a fake cert, but a valid one.  Or mapping another address with a valid cert to the aks ingress IP and using that in the custom hostname origin group configuration.